# Passing php post variables obtained by angular function

Tags: php, angularjs

This is my code:

```
<form role="form" action="foo.php" method="post">
                        <p ng-repeat="item in selectedItems | orderBy: 'ora'">
                            Campo numero: {{item.id}} Orario: {{item.ora}}:00 Prezzo: €{{prezzoOra()}}.00
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <b>Ore totali:</b> {{selectedItems.length}}<br>
                            <b>Prezzo Totale:</b> €{{total(selectedItems)}}.00
                        </p>
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{total(selectedItems)}}" name="totale" id="totale" />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Indietro</button>

                        <input type="submit" value="Procedi con il pagamento" ng-click="prenota(selectedItems)" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

When i try to get the $_POST['totale'] in the foo.php page the result that i obtain is always 0.

prenota function:

```
$scope.prenota = function(selectedItems) {

    for(var i = 0, len = $scope.selectedItems.length; i < len; i++) {

        var id = selectedItems[i].id;
        var ora = selectedItems[i].ora;

        $http.post(base_path + "prenotazione/campi/prenota", {'id': id, 'ora': ora, 'data': $scope.data}).success(function(data,status,headers,config){

            $scope.myPromise =  $http.post(base_path + "prenotazione/campi/data", {'data': $scope.data}).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
                                    $scope.disponibilita = data;
                                });
        });

    }


    $scope.selectedItems = [];

};
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it will work with the value set like that.
And then set the input using an ng-value (AngularJS >=v1.2) instead of interpolating the scope.

```
<input type="hidden" ng-value="total(selectedItems)" name="totale" id="totale" />
```

Also, are you using the native form submission from the browser or are you posting through an ajax request in the function `prenota`? It could help to know the contents of this function.

Comment: yes in the prenota function there is an ajax request

Comment: Can you share the code that makes the request? The issue is most certainly there. :)